# Google Sheets ImportXML to display Headlines and embed the URL

Tags: regex, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets `ImportXML`, I am looking to display the Headlines AND also become a link to click on. 
The below code provides us with the URL only. 
If I remove `//a/@href` it just gives me the text. Any way to combine the two?

```
=QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://www.marketbeat.com/stocks/NASDAQ/ALLK/news/","//div[@id='dvHeadlines']/table//a/@href"),"SELECT * LIMIT 10")
```

Comment: and you want it doubled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK(UNIQUE(
 QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://www.marketbeat.com/stocks/NASDAQ/ALLK/news/",
 "//div[@id='dvHeadlines']/table//a/@href"), "limit 10")), 
 QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://www.marketbeat.com/stocks/NASDAQ/ALLK/news/",
 "//div[@id='dvHeadlines']/table//a"), "where Col1 is not null limit 5")))
```

[image: 0]

---

new line fix:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK(UNIQUE(
 QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://www.marketbeat.com/stocks/NASDAQ/ALLK/news/",
 "//div[@id='dvHeadlines']/table//a/@href"), "limit 10")), 
 REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://www.marketbeat.com/stocks/NASDAQ/ALLK/news/",
 "//div[@id='dvHeadlines']/table//a"), "where Col1 is not null limit 5"), "\n", )))
```

[image: 0]